# Deleted question showing up in 'newest questions' tab

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, deleted-questions, question-lists

Well, I already searched meta as well as cleared my browser cache.  I realize this may be a SO cache problem, but it still seems kind of strange to me.

[image]

The deleted question is [this one, for 10k users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13204627/basic-new-to-php)(assuming it still exists).

Shouldn't deleted questions only be visible to 10k users?  I'm only at 2k.

Comment: The lists are indeed cached, and deleted questions may still show in the list for a short time before they disappear.

Comment: @animuson Do you know how much time that constitutes?

Comment: I have no idea, I think it depends on when the cache was last updated and which list, but generally I don't see deleted questions in lists more than a minute after they get deleted.

Comment: @Shog9 Why is this by design?

Comment: Caching is necessary for performance reasons. Deleted question visibility should be brief, but sometimes is unavoidable.